# How can check what sites thin is hosting on a windows machine?

Tags: thin, dashing

I have installed [dashing](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/) and set up a on a windows 8 machine, which uses the [thin webserver](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/). However, when I run

```
>dashing start -p 1338
```

and navigate to `http://localhost:1338`, chrome cannot load the page.

How can I see a list of everything that thin is currently serving to make sure it's hosting the site correctly?

Comment: If you're having issues with a fresh install of dashing on a windows machine failing silently, dashing requires the twitter gem, running `>gem install twitter` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts to make sure localhost is routed to 127.0.0.1.

If that's setup you can can see on what NICs thin is available on by going in to cmd and running 'netstat -an' Which should give an ip address in the list with port 1338.

Finally you can use telnet to try to connect from the comand line: 'telnet 127.0.0.1 1338'.

HTH,

Comment: The hosts file needed updating, and netstat didn't show anything listening at 127.0.01:1338, and the telnet connection failed. Now to see why dashing didn't start properly